# Nutcracker Tevilah

Tags: tevilas-keilim-dipping

Does a Nutcracker need tevilah? What about Poultry Scissors? Can opener?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Poultry scissors: no. [From the Star-K](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-containers-tevilas.htm):

> Utensils used exclusively with raw, non-edible food, for instance cookie cutters or a metal tenderizer hammer do not need tevila.

(Assuming you only use them for raw poultry.)

Can opener: [no, again from the Star-K](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-containers-tevilasguide.htm).

> `Can Opener         No Tevila`

Nutcracker is an interesting one. Nuts are edible raw; the question is if the nutcracker is viewed as coming in contact with the edible food (like a carrot peeler), which would necessitate tevila; or if it's analogous to a can opener, which is only intended to cut apart the metal and leave the food alone. UPDATE: the Star-K replied via email that yes, it must be toveled.

Comment: Their website says -  Nutcracker Tevilah with a brocha, if used at the table.  Tevilah without a brocha, if not used at the table.  https://www.star-k.org/articles/kosher-lists/1170/tevilas-keilim-guidelines/

Comment: Star-K website mentions shears specifically as needing Tevilah. Whether or not you are supposed to recite a Berachah depends on its use. https://www.star-k.org/articles/kosher-lists/1170/tevilas-keilim-guidelines/